# What is NSString internally?

Tags: nsstring, spidermonkey

Can I assign a char* or wchar_t* to the NSString and completely avoid copying some how?

I need to pass Unicode (utf16 LE) string from SpiderMonkey to UIView subclass, and my goal is to avoid copying if possible, or at least avoid intermediate conversion to UTF8.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

`- (instancetype)initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding freeWhenDone:(BOOL)flag`

method of NSString class.